# Por qué la diferencia al retornar los valores?

Tags: javascript, recursión

En este código, cuando el largo del array, llega a 100, EFECTIVAMENTE retorna 0.

```js
function multiplos(arr) {
  if(arr.length > 100) {return arr;}
  else {
  arr.push(arr[arr.length-1]*2);
  return multiplos(arr);
  }
}
console.log(multiplos([2]));
```

Entonces porqué aqui no retorna también, sino que retorna el resultado esperado?, en cambio en el anterior ejemplo debo retornar el array, porque sino me devuelve 0.

```js
 function sum(nums) {
   if (nums.length === 0) {
      console.log("Sí llegé a 0");
      return 0;
    } else {
       const [first, ...rest] = nums;
       return first + sum(rest);
    }
 }
console.log(sum([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

**Edición:**

```js
function multiplos(arr) {
  if(arr.length > 100) {return 0;}
  else {
  arr.push(arr[arr.length-1]*2);
  return arr + multiplos(arr);
  }
}
console.log(multiplos([2]));
```

Según lo que me ha respondido Asier, es por que se suman y efectivamente aquí lo veo, ya que al parecer lo que se va acumulando es el lo que está antes de la suma, osea `"return **arr** + multiplos(arr)"`, aún así tengo la duda de si realmente es así, y por qué no lo devuelve como array?

Comment: Si te das cuenta, ambas funciones recursivas cuando se cumple el if, retornan 0, pero el primer ejemplo retorna efectivamente 0, y el segundo no lo hace.

Comment: Sólo llega a 0 en la última llamada. Hasta ese punto has ido sumando cada uno de los valores de la lista.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creo que todas estas dudas se pueden aclarar a la vez, explicando bien cómo funciona la recursividad. Por tanto, expliquemos los conceptos básicos:

Una función recursiva es aquella que se llama a sí misma. Dejemos la recursividad indirecta a un lado (la función A llama a la función B, que a su vez vuelve a llamar a A) para simplificar.

Una función recursiva debe tener 2 casos bien diferenciados:

- El caso base, que es el caso trivial en el que la recursividad no se usa. Por ejemplo, si queremos sumar todos los elementos de un array, el caso base es cuando el array está vacío. En ese caso devolvemos 0 y la ejecución acaba ahí.
- El caso recursivo, que es el caso no trivial. En este caso lo que se hace es descomponer el problema a resolver en problemas más pequeños. Una vez los problemas más pequeños se han solucionado, el problema original se resuelve con la unión de todas las soluciones, ya sea sumando, concatenando, multiplicando... etc.

Una vez entendemos los casos, podemos pasar a diseñar una solución a nuestro problema. Pongamos por ejemplo el caso de sumar todos los elementos de un array:

```
var ejemplo=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

El caso base sería cuando queremos sumar los elementos de un array vacío:

```
var ejemplo2=[];
```

En ese caso el valor resultante es cero, así pues pongamos eso en nuestra función:

```
function sumaArray(array) {
  //caso base
  if (array.length===0) {
    return 0;
  }
  //caso recursivo
  //... por definir
}
```

Entonces tenemos el caso recursivo: Si tenemos un array con N elementos donde N es mayor que 0, tomemos el primer elemento. Entonces tenemos por un lado un elemento E y por otro un array con N-1 elementos. Acabamos de reducir el problema, pasando de N a N-1. Por tanto, el resultado sería sumar el E más la suma del resto de elementos. Añadamos el caso recursivo a nuestra función y probémosla:

```js
function sumaArray(array) {
  //caso base
  if (array.length===0) {
  console.log('sumArray() da 0');
    return 0;
  }
  const e=array[0];
  const arrayConUnElementoMenos=array.slice(1); //devuelve el array menos el primer elemento
  console.log(`Devuelvo la suma de ${e} y el resultado de sumArray(${arrayConUnElementoMenos})`);
  return e + sumaArray(arrayConUnElementoMenos);
}

console.log(sumaArray([1,2,3,4]));
```

Si, como en tu primer ejemplo, en lugar de devolver `e + sumaArray(arrayConUnElementoMenos);` hubiésemos devuelto simplemente `sumaArray(arrayConUnElementoMenos);`, no estaríamos acumulando nada, simplemente se devolvería el caso base (0) olvidando los resultados intermedios.

Quizá tu segundo ejemplo es complicado de entender por la notación usada:

```
const [first, ...rest] = nums;
```

Esta línea es equivalente a lo que he puesto en mi ejemplo:

```
const first=nums[0]; //primer elemento del array nums
const rest=nums.slice(1); // resto de elementos del array
```

Y tu último ejemplo falla en que estás sumando un array a un número. Javascript, cuando intentas sumar tipos de datos que no son compatibles, lo que hace es transformar ambos tipos a texto (strings) y concatenarlos:

```js
var array = [2,4,6,8];
var numero= 0;
var texto= 'hola';
var objeto={};

console.log(array + numero);
console.log(array+texto);
console.log(objeto + array);
```

Comment: y qué es mejor, ir acumulando o ir haciendo directamente el push en el array como mi primer ejemplo?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es la sumatoria, no crees el array porque estás usando memoria innecesariamente, simplemente suma y devuelve el acumulado

Comment: Gracias pablo LOZANO !!

Answer (score 2):

El primer caso devuelve 0 porque la última llamada a la función recursiva devuelve 0 y el resto de llamadas devuelven el resultado tal cual:

```
return multiplo(arr);  //devuelve 0
return multiplo(arr);  //devuelve 0
return multiplo(arr);  //devuelve 0
return multiplo(arr);  //devuelve 0
.....
return multiplo(arr);  //devuelve 0
return multiplo(arr);  //devuelve 0
return 0;
```

En el segundo caso la última llamada devuelve también 0 pero las anteriores suman un valor al resultado antes de devolverlo:

```
return 0 + sum(rest); // devuelve 45
return 1 + sum(rest); // devuelve 45
return 2 + sum(rest); // devuelve 44
return 3 + sum(rest); // devuelve 42
return 4 + sum(rest); // devuelve 39
return 5 + sum(rest); // devuelve 35
return 6 + sum(rest); // devuelve 30
return 7 + sum(rest); // devuelve 24
return 8 + sum(rest); // devuelve 17
return 9 + sum(rest); // devuelve 9
return 0;
```

Comment: Asier, edité un poco mi pregunta .

Answer (score 2):

Es por que las dos funciones recursivas funcionan de forma diferente:

La **primera** función simplemente retorna el resultado de la función recursiva.

```
return multiplos(arr);
```

Es decir , retorna el último valor , o sea `0`, como efectivamente resulta:

La **segunda** función retorna el primer elemento más el resultado de la función recursiva, por eso da `45`:  haciendo un debug esto seria lo que pasaría

```
console.log(sum([0,1,2]))
```

en primera instancia el tamaño del array es `3`, entonces retorna

```
0 + sum([1,2])  //
```

ahora el array es de longitud `2`, entonces retorna

```
1 + sum([2])
```

ahora el array es de longitud `1`, entonces retorna

```
2 + sum([])
```

ahora si retorna `0` , es decir, que sumando las respuestas

```
 2 + sum([]) = 2  // 2 + 0 
 1 + sum([2]) = 3 // 1 + el resultado anterior es decir 2
 0 + sum([1,2]) = 3 // 0 + el resultado anterior es decir 3
```

entonces , el resultado sera  `3` , por la suma se va acumulando.

para que returne `0`, tu función debería ser de esta forma

```js
 function sum(nums) {
   if (nums.length === 0) {
      console.log("Sí llegé a 0");
      return 0;
    } else {
       const [first, ...rest] = nums;
       return sum(rest);
    }
 }
console.log(sum([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Por que no implementas la funcion así?

```
function sum(nums) {
   var i = 0;
   for (var j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) { i += nums[j]; }
   return i;
 }
console.log(sum([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Tiene mas sentido que usar recursividad.